# Is there any interoperability between GRASS and PCRaster?

Tags: grass-gis

After having looked at PCraster river network it seems that GRASS makes better work. But PCRaster is the best for building models. So is it really possible to use python-grass scripts for delineation and them convert them to .map and work through PCRaster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use r.import and r.out.gdal with the https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pcraster.html driver to import and export between GRASS GIS and PCRaster. This should also work in a Python context. For related code snippets, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python .